# need way to close datebook when shown inline

Tags: datebox

I am using the stable version jQM DateBox with JQM 1.4.5 and jQuery 2.

I have a popup form that has a datebook widget on it.  I use inline blind because the initial value is set for the date.  But the user can click into the field, the datebook opens up the calendar and the user can pick a new date.

However, if the user opens up the datebook calendar, there's no way to close it without them picking a date.  It would be nice if either clicking on the date field again closes the calendar (like a toggle) or there's an explicit close button that is shown when the calendar is shown.

Thanks.